# Storing a Parcelable object to a File in Android

Tags: android, file, object, bundle, parcelable

I am trying to store an ArrayList of ResolveInfo objects to a file so that I don't have to rebuild it each time my application launches (about 4-6 seconds) ResolveInfo objects are Parcelable, but not Serializable so I get a java.io error when I try to write the objects.

I have stored them in my savedInstanceState bundle, but that doesn't help when closing the application. Am I doing something plain wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

savedInstance info will not save across multiple sessions. You will really want to implement `Serializable` to save your `ResolveInfo`.

Comment: Would I have to subclass ResolveInfo as something like SerializableResolveInfo who implements Serializble? And looking at ResolveInfo he has a member of type ActivityInfo and type IntentFilter. Would I have to make a serializable version of them as well?

This seems like a huge process for something fairly trivial. Is there any other way to cache this data, so that it doesn't need to be loaded every time?

Anyway I guess I'll move on with this project without saving the list and deal with the slow start for now.